# everyauth: How do I return the form data from validateRegistration

Tags: node.js, express, everyauth

I use the password module of everyauth and I do some validation upon registration in the validateRegistration method, push some errors, fulfill the promise and return it back. But this way I'm missing the form data (i.e. the entered email, first, last name, etc) in my view and the user have to enter them again.

Here is my validateRegistration method:

```
.validateRegistration (newUserAttrs, errors) ->
  login = newUserAttrs.email;
  promise = @Promise()

  if !newUserAttrs.name.first
      errors.push 'Missing first name'

  if !newUserAttrs.name.last
     errors.push 'Missing last name'

  userManager.getUser "Custom", login, (user, err) ->
    if user
      errors.push('User with the same email already exists!')      
    promise.fulfill errors

  return promise
```

And my jade view

```
form(action='/register', method='POST')
    label(for='firstName') First Name
    input(type='text', name='firstName')    

    label(for='lastName') Last Name
    input(type='text', name='lastName')    

    label(for=everyauth.password.loginFormFieldName) Email
    input(type='text', name=everyauth.password.loginFormFieldName)

    label(for=everyauth.password.passwordFormFieldName) Password
    input(type='password', name=everyauth.password.passwordFormFieldName)
```

Do you have any suggestions how can I pass the form data back to the view so I can fill up the form fields?

Thanks